# Contacting a company recruiter inquiring about a job application status

Tags: job-search, internship, linkedin, follow-up

So, I really want to work for this one company. I have tried following up (both, via Gmail and LinkedIn's InMail) on my application to one of the company recruiters, but in vain. May I please know what am I supposed to do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: No. I haven't because I do not have the recruiter's telephone number. Also, wouldn't it be inappropriate to do so?

Comment: Why would it be inappropriate to do so? Just a friendly "Hi, just wanted to catchup with my application/make sure you've received my previous emails" would suffice.

Comment: Joe, I am afraid it will not be an easy task finding that recruiter's contact number. Also, I would like to add that this person isn't the only recruiter on LinkedIn under University Relations. There are two more, but I think if I pass along the same message to one of the other recruiters, since they are on each other's network, it would not seem like a good idea.

Comment: And, may I please know why is this question down-voted? At least provide a reason before doing so.

Comment: I'm guessing it is because it depends on a company's process what you're supposed to do next or how long you are to wait for a response, which makes it something we just can't tell you (unless one of those recruiters happens to be a member of this site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to work for this company, but you really don't know if they want you to work for them.  You've applied, and followed up on the application.  Now, what you do is wait and move on.

- If you pester them, you take the chance of making them not want to deal with you at all.  This includes phoning.  If the application process said to email or apply online, then follow their process.  They want to hire people who can follow directions and understand professional norms.
- Companies can move very slowly, even if they are interested.  Hiring managers and HR people take vacations, budgets need to be approved, emails need to be answered.  Just because it is taking a long time to you, doesn't mean that things aren't moving along nicely in their world.
- It's best, unless you're already happily employed and this job option is one of the few that looks even better, to keep applying for other jobs too.  Applying and waiting is very inefficient (especially in light of the next point).
- If a company doesn't have any interest, they often don't respond at all.  If you sit waiting by your phone, you'll experience a lot of frustration.  It is better to move on and think about the next job opportunity as well.  If they call for an interview, if they call back with a job offer -- let those be happy surprises.

You can't force them to hire you.  You don't even know that you're the best among all the people who apply.  So the only thing you can do is adjust your expectations, and relax.  (Oh, and spend some time reading [Ask A Manager](http://www.askamanager.org), so that if you are called for an interview, you know how to prepare.)

Comment: May I please ask another quick question too in the same thread? Will it be best to approach companies via the company's recruiters or a simple online application would suffice? Thanks.

Comment: @user1302 if you have another question make sure to make a [new question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and not just add it here.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. My bad.